# Working with carouFredSel : items getting margin-right added

Tags: jquery, tabs, carousel

I m using the below mentioned code to display the carousel for items. The carousel should display 3 items with scrolling facility if more items are available.

But i am facing an issue when i have less than 3 items in the carousel container .
`tabCarouselContainer.carouFredSel({
                    auto: false,
                    height : "auto",
                    width : "100%",
                    items: {
                        visible         : 3,
                        minimum         : 3,
                        width           : 190,
                        height          : 110
                    },
                    circular: true,

                    responsive: false,

                    direction: "left",

                    padding: null,
                    scroll: {
                        items           : 1,
                        easing          : "linear",
                        fx              : "scroll",
                        duration        : 500,
                        timeoutDuration : 500
                    },
                    prev: {
                        button          : function() { return tab.find('.nav-prev'); }
                    },
                    next: {
                        button          : function() { return tab.find('.nav-next'); }
                    }

                });`
[image: tabs with 2 items only getting displayed]

As seen above, i have 2 items but only one is visible. I have checked in firebug there is on more item, which is having margin-right :190px hence it is going outside the div width and hence not visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the css property for the third item via javascript. did not find any jquery solution for it like adding some property,etc.